# Button images not working on device

Tags: iphone, uibutton

so, I made my app and everything, and it has a few UI buttons with background images, which worked fine when it was on the computer and i was testing in iphone sim.
now, when i test on a real iphone, the buttons just show up as standard UICustomWhiteRect or whatever it is called.
here is the code i use to make them:

```
filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
            pathForResource:@"button-half@2x" 
            ofType:@"png"];
[sendAsOneSMSButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filepath] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

i also have one for when it is pressed, which i set just like that. and just so no one asks me, **the images for the buttons are both in my main folder the same folder my .xcodeproj file is in.**
what could i be doing wrong?

SO:
they work in iPhone Simulator,
they show up as normal buttons without images on a real iPhone.

Comment: A note: you don't need to do all of that to get the image you're after. `[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-half"]` will give you the same thing, and even automatically selects between regular-resolution and Retina graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check in a case like this is whether your images are really named "button-half@2x.png", or if they are in fact "button-half@2x.PNG", "button-half@2X.png", or the like. The usual filesystem on OS X (and therefore on the simulator) is case-insensitive, while the filesystem on the device is case-sensitive.

Comment: AHH thank you!! now i feel bad for wasting everyones time. i used a capital B instead of a lowercase b in "button"

Comment: @josherick: No problem. I don't know if we've all run into that bug once, but I sure have.

Comment: wait no it didnt work. i completly deleted the images and then removed the references from the target and the sidebar thing, and then i added them again as "button-half@2x.png" with the checkbox checked.

I also tried them as [UIImage imageNamed:@"button-half@2x"] like noah witherspoon suggested with no result.

Comment: OK NOW IT WORKED WOW. so i basically just renamed it and made a completly new image and stuff but i kept one of them but the other one i didnt keep i just deleted the @2x and resized it so i'm not sure what the problem was my image was probably just screwed up somehow. but thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image file is included in the Bundle Resources folder.

Comment: if they are in the folder my .xcodeproj file is in, is this the same thing?

Comment: No, go to the target, then Build Phases, then Copy Bundle Resources, and make sure the file shows up there. If not, add it and try running on the device again.